# Unable to use face api snapshot

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, face-api

I created a snapshot for one of my person group. However when I want to apply it I got 400 error.What is the reason? Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Its too brief in your query , could you pls provide more info such as something like exception information ?

Comment: Sorry, the exception is permission denied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [this API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/snapshot-take) to create your face API snapshot and use [this API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/snapshot-apply) to apply your snapshot and got a 400 error with exception : permission denied . Pls have a check if you have configed your snapshot apply scope correctly while you creating your snapshots.

In [take snapshot API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/snapshot-take) , there is a param `applyScope` defines which subscription could use this snapshot . If you want to apply this snapshot in your face API subscription , you should define your face API subscription ID there.

You can find your ID here on Azure Portal :

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Stanley! It works ! But is there any documents mentioned applyscope ? I can’t find any details about it on api reference .

Comment: Hi @JackGronru , this is the only doc that I can find mentioned it : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/how-to-migrate-face-data#take-a-snapshot-of-a-persongroup